# AMC 2012 Junior Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

$x^2 +y^2 +z^2 = 100x+10y+z $. Find the smallest number and largest number that fit the equation.The numbers are below 1000
I am just baffled at the question.Is there a way to tackle such questions?

Comment: Do you mean find the smallest and largest numbers under 1000 which equal the sum of their squared digits?

Comment: Yeap.that right

Comment: I assume you meant $z^2$ instead of writing $x^2$ twice?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi What's the largest that the LHS could possibly be?  That gives you an upper bound for the first digit $x$.  Now, knowing that, what's the largest the LHS could possibly be?  You now have a pretty good idea of what $x$ is.  You even get some information about how big $y$ can be...

Comment: Looks like a complete-the-square type problem. I haven't tried it, but these seem to be the trick in every other AMC problem.

Comment: Yep,$z^2$ instead of $x^2$ for the third one.My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum sum of three square digits is $9^2+9^2+9^2=243$, so first digit of any solution must be 0,1,2.

But that means that the maximum sum of three square digits in any solution is $2^2+9^2+9^2=166$, so first digit must be 0 or 1.

If the number is in the range 100-166, then the maximum sum of its squared digits is either $1^2+6^2+6^2=73$ if the 2nd digit is 6, or $1^2+5^2+9^2=107$ if the 2nd digit is less than 6. So if the number is in the range 100-166, it must be in the range 100-107, but all such numbers have digit sum at most $1^2+0^2+7^2<100$, so first digit is 0.

So $x=0$ and we have $y^2+z^2=10y+z$. Hence $(y-5)^2=25-z(z-1)$. The LHS is non-negative, so $z(z-1)\le25$, so $z=0,1,2,3,4$ or 5 giving LHS$=25,25,23,19,13,5$ respectively. But the LHS is a square, so the only solutions are that the number is 0 or 1.

Comment: Don't understand from paragraph 3 onwarda

Comment: Para 4. Do you understand as far as $(y-5)^2=25-z(z-1)$?

Comment: Why use $1^2 + 5^2 + 9^2?

Comment: @almagest I could understand your reasoning, but it was a little difficult in the first reading. Could you please make your answer a little clearer?

Comment: @shardulc Is that better?

Comment: @almagest Yes, thanks!

Comment: Okay I finally understand!!! Thanks